# EclipseRCP - Databind text with a constant value added at the end

Tags: java, data-binding, eclipse-rcp

I have a simple scale with a range of  0 - 100. I bound that to a label via `WindowsBuilder`. I want the text to display the numerical value on the scale and a `%` following that. How would I go about doing this?

The source code was generated by `Windows Builder`

```
    protected DataBindingContext initDataBindings() {
    DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
    //
    IObservableValue observeTextLblPercentObserveWidget = WidgetProperties.text().observe(lblPercent);
    IObservableValue observeSelectionScaleObserveWidget = WidgetProperties.selection().observe(scale);
    bindingContext.bindValue(observeTextLblPercentObserveWidget, observeSelectionScaleObserveWidget, null, null);
    //
    return bindingContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you may do it in WindowsBuilder, but you need to add org.eclipse.core.databinding.conversion.IConverter.

Actually I think you'll need two converters (from model to text that appends "%" and one for reverse convertion to parse user input) and a validator.